# Изменения значений в объекте JS

Tags: javascript

Застрял на одной задачке, не могу понять, что делаю не так. Нужно было написать функцию, которая принимает объект как аргумент и возвращает новый объект. Только с полями, у которых тип значения - строка. Основным условием было решение через `reduce`.

> Пример: `Input: { name: 'pilot', isActive: true };` 
> Actions: 
> Output: `{ name: 'pilot' }`

Написал вот такой код, но не знаю, как именно его изменить...

```js
function test(param) {
  const keys = Object.keys(param)
  return Object.entries(param)
    .filter((item) => typeof item[1] === `string`)
    .reduce((acc, item, index) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [keys[index]]: item
      }
    }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создавать переменную `keys` с ключами объекта совсем не обязательно; все ключи будут получены из вывода `Object.entries()`.

```js
var obj = {
  1: 'value',
  2: true,
};

Object.entries(obj) // [ [1, 'value'], [2, true] ]
```

Метод `Array.filter` уберет из многомерного массива все элементы(массивы *[ключ, значение]*), где тип значения `string`. Это лишниий проход по массиву в цикле.

```js
Object.entries(param)
      .filter((item) => typeof item[1] === `string`); // лишний цикл, проверку можно выполнить в reduce
```

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```js
const obj = { 
  name: 'pilot',
  surname: 'auto',
  1: null,
  2: 20,
  isActive: true 
};

function test(param) {
  return Object.entries(param)
               .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => { // деструктурируем аргумент с текущим элементом 
                  if (typeof value == 'string') acc[key] = value; // если значение типа string добавляем свойство в объект аккумулятор 
                  return acc;
                }, {});
}

console.log(test(obj));
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries` - возвращает двухуровневый массив, где первый элемент - ключ, второй - значение. На каждом этапе reduce проверяем, что второй элемент имеет тип `string`. Если это так, добавляем в копию нового объекта наш элемент, если нет - просто возвращаем текущую копию

Что-то в этом роде получается

```js
let obj =  { name: 'pilot', isActive: true };

const res = Object.entries(obj)
.reduce((acc, item)=>{
if(typeof item[1] === 'string'){
    return { ...acc, [ item[0] ] : item[1] };
}
return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Cпасиобо, за подсказку)